# Excluding Image From the CSS of Animatable Property

Tags: jquery, html, css

I applied following CSS to the post article which affects a background change of color-

```
 .post-article{   
     background: green;
     -webkit-animation: mymove 15s; 
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
     from {background-color: green;}
     to {background-color: blue;}
 }
```

Now, this article post contains am image and the CSS has affected the image, too! I want to selectively exclude this image class (which is .article img )from being affected due to this CSS. So, I used-

```
.post-article:not(.article img){   
     background: green;
     -webkit-animation: mymove 15s; 
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
     from {background-color: green;}
     to {background-color: blue;}
 }
```

But the desired change didn't occur and all elements continue to be affected. Any guidelines?

Minified versiion of HTML;

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.post-article {  width: 300px;
height: 200px;  
background: green;
-webkit-animation: mymove 15s; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
from {background-color: green;}
to {background-color: blue;}
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="post-article"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should share (a minified version of) your HTML too.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shrLLnpj/ that should roughly be the code and its working, i dont really understand the problem or how the behaviour should be

Comment: Where's the `<img>` which you don't want animated?

Answer (score 0):

Add another div in-between, I think it should work :

```
<div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/400x200" />
    <div class="post-article">
        <p >lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not practical, images could be multiple.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, you could have other images, what would it change ?

Comment: I mean, this code should be applicable to all the images that would be included in all future posts.